# PHP uploader and downloader file size limit

Tags: php, cordova, phonegap-plugins, file-transfer

I have an upload php script, that uploads a file to my server with a random name (without extension)

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    //Read parameters
    $documentuniqueid = addslashes($_REQUEST['did']);

    //Get file name
    $filename = urldecode($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    //Move file to folder
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "docs/".$documentuniqueid);
?>
```

I can upload an image from my iPhone without any errors (via a PhoneGap app, using the FileTransfer plugin), but when I download that file to my Desktop, add the ".jpg" extension to it, the image will be corrupted (with random vertical lines in it)

Also, for downloading, I use the following PHP script:

```
<?php
    ...reading parameters...
    $original_filename = "http://www.example.com/docs/".$document_id;
    $new_filename = $real_document_name;    

    //Complex header (NOT USED, but I also tried this, where the content-type is specified exactly for JPGs
    //headers to send your file
    //header("Content-Type: application/jpeg");
    //header("Content-Length: " . filesize($original_filename));
    //header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $new_filename . '"');      

    //Second one
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    header('Content-Type: '.finfo_file($finfo, $original_filename));
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($original_filename));
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$new_filename.'"');      

    //clean up
    ob_clean();
    flush();

    readfile($original_filename);          
    exit();
?>
```

It works fine for files that are ~700 KBs, but for files from my iPhone which are 4MB, it's not working anymore.

Should I specify a max file size somewhere?